# split by lookaround

Tags: r, regex, regex-lookarounds, strsplit

I want to split a string into individual chars except those surrounded by `<` and `>`. Hence `<a>bc<d>e` would become `<a>` `b` `c` `<d>` `e`. I tried `(?<!<)(?!>)`, which seems to work in a regex tester but not in the following code in R. What did I do wrong?

```
X = '<a>bc<d>e'
Y = '(?<!<)(?!>)'
unlist(strsplit(X,Y,perl=TRUE))
[1] "<" "a" ">" "b" "c" "<" "d" ">" "e"
```

Comment: It seem to be something related to Rs regex flavor. You can try `stringi::stri_split_regex(X, Y, omit_empty = TRUE)` instead

Comment: I added a couple positive lookarounds to Y and that seems to do the trick. I guess strsplit won't split unless you actually tell it to look for something that's there.
`Y = '(?<!<)(?!>)(?<=.)(?=.)'`

Comment: In the [source code](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/8d91521d0dadea2a2156e564f685c828980e10fd/src/main/grep.c#L426), there is some hint on empty string matches: "*Careful: need to distinguish empty (rm_eo == 0) from
        non-empty (rm_eo > 0) matches.  In the former case, the
        token extracted is the next character.  Otherwise, it is
        everything before the start of the match, which may be
        the empty string (not a "token'' in the strict sense).*"

Answer (score 2):

Use **positive** lookarounds instead of negative ones:

```
strsplit('<a>bc<d>e', '(?<=[^<])(?=[^>])', perl=TRUE)
## [[1]]
## [1] "<a>" "b"   "c"   "<d>" "e"
```

See the [R demo](https://rextester.com/FFHE36011).

**Details**

- `(?<=[^<])` - a positive lookbehind that requires a char other than `<` immediately to the left of the current location
- `(?=[^>])` - a positive lookahead that requires a char other than `>` immediately to the right of the current location.

Answer (score 1):

```
(<[^>]+>|\S)
```

Seems to work. This tries to first match triangle brackets with all they encase, and if not, matches a single character.

[Example on Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/JCvUeQ/3)

```
regmatches(X, gregexpr("<[^>]+>|\\S",X))[[1]]
#> [1] "<a>" "b"   "c"   "<d>" "e"
```

Comment: it works but it won't work with `strsplit`, which requires a regex for separators and has a special case to split every character, I allowed myself to edit your post to make your proposal work.